# How can I undo the previous step in Windows Workflow Foundation?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, workflow-foundation-4

I have a project that uses Windows Workflow and I have a database in SQL Server 2008 with Workflow tables.

I want to Edit Record in Project so want to go back to a previous Activity without condition, and update the workflow instance in database.

How can I undo the previous step in Windows Workflow Foundation?

Comment: http://www.biztalkgurus.com/windows_workflow/b/workflow-syn/archive/2011/03/29/wf4-rolling-your-own-undo-units-in-workflow-designer-net-4-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not really. There is a bit if hack though that might be useful. When you use a workflow instance store and tell the workflow to abandon it's state when an unhandled exception occurs the last saved state in the instance store is unchanged. So you can reload the workflow from that state and continue as if the next activity never executed. The problem is in controlling when the workflow persist. You get to control that for the most part but there are some circumstances where a workflow will always persist.